# Mapview NullPointerException android

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-mapview

I am using `Mapview` for displaying maps.

When I go to my map `MapFragment.java` which holds `Mapview` **for first time** I shows perfect.

When I change my `Fragmet` and come to the screen once again it crashes .

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void maps.af.y.q()' on a null object reference**

If required code I can post it.

Comment: Please post your codes and share also the encountered error that appears in the logs.